# Scrape Table Data on Multiple Pages from Multiple URLs (Python & BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

New coder here! I am trying to scrape web table data from multiple URLs. Each URL web-page has 1 table, however that table is split among multiple pages. My code only iterates through the table pages of the first URL and not the rest. So.. I am able to get pages 1-5 of NBA data for year 2000 only, but it stops there. How do I get my code to pull every year of data? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
page = 1
year = 2000

while page < 20 and year < 2020:
  base_URL = 'http://www.espn.com/nba/salaries/_/year/{}/page/{}'.format(year,page) 
  response = requests.get(base_URL, headers)


if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    sal_table = soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'tablehead')
    if len(sal_table) < 2:
        sal_table = sal_table[0]
        with open ('NBA_Salary_2000_2019.txt', 'a') as r:
            for row in sal_table.find_all('tr'):
                for cell in row.find_all('td'):
                    r.write(cell.text.ljust(30))
                r.write('\n')
        page+=1
    else:
        print("too many tables")
else:
    year +=1
    page = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd consider using pandas here as 1) it's `.read_html()` function (which uses beautifulsoup under the hood), is easier to parse `<table>` tags, and 2) it can easily then write straight to file.

Also, it's a waste to iterate through 20 pages (for example the first season you are after only has 4 pages...the rest are blank. So I'd consider adding something that says once it reaches a blank table, move on to the next season.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'}

results = pd.DataFrame()
year = 2000

while year < 2020:
    goToNextPage = True
    page = 1
    while goToNextPage == True:
        base_URL = 'http://www.espn.com/nba/salaries/_/year/{}/page/{}'.format(year,page) 
        response = requests.get(base_URL, headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            temp_df = pd.read_html(base_URL)[0]
            temp_df.columns = list(temp_df.iloc[0,:])
            temp_df = temp_df[temp_df['RK'] != 'RK']

            if len(temp_df) == 0:
                goToNextPage = False
                year +=1
                continue


            print ('Aquiring Season: %s\tPage: %s' %(year, page))

            temp_df['Season'] = '%s-%s' %(year-1, year)

            results = results.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

            page+=1


results.to_csv('c:/test/NBA_Salary_2000_2019.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.head(25).to_string())
    RK                     NAME                    TEAM       SALARY     Season
0    1      Shaquille O'Neal, C      Los Angeles Lakers  $17,142,000  1999-2000
1    2        Kevin Garnett, PF  Minnesota Timberwolves  $16,806,000  1999-2000
2    3       Alonzo Mourning, C              Miami Heat  $15,004,000  1999-2000
3    4         Juwan Howard, PF      Washington Wizards  $15,000,000  1999-2000
4    5       Scottie Pippen, SF  Portland Trail Blazers  $14,795,000  1999-2000
5    6          Karl Malone, PF               Utah Jazz  $14,000,000  1999-2000
6    7         Larry Johnson, F         New York Knicks  $11,910,000  1999-2000
7    8          Gary Payton, PG     Seattle SuperSonics  $11,020,000  1999-2000
8    9      Rasheed Wallace, PF  Portland Trail Blazers  $10,800,000  1999-2000
9   10            Shawn Kemp, C     Cleveland Cavaliers  $10,780,000  1999-2000
10  11     Damon Stoudamire, PG  Portland Trail Blazers  $10,125,000  1999-2000
11  12      Antonio McDyess, PF          Denver Nuggets   $9,900,000  1999-2000
12  13       Antoine Walker, PF          Boston Celtics   $9,000,000  1999-2000
13  14  Shareef Abdur-Rahim, PF     Vancouver Grizzlies   $9,000,000  1999-2000
14  15        Allen Iverson, SG      Philadelphia 76ers   $9,000,000  1999-2000
15  16            Vin Baker, PF     Seattle SuperSonics   $9,000,000  1999-2000
16  17            Ray Allen, SG         Milwaukee Bucks   $9,000,000  1999-2000
17  18    Anfernee Hardaway, SF            Phoenix Suns   $9,000,000  1999-2000
18  19          Kobe Bryant, SF      Los Angeles Lakers   $9,000,000  1999-2000
19  20      Stephon Marbury, PG         New Jersey Nets   $9,000,000  1999-2000
20  21           Vlade Divac, C        Sacramento Kings   $8,837,000  1999-2000
21  22         Bryant Reeves, C     Vancouver Grizzlies   $8,666,000  1999-2000
22  23        Tom Gugliotta, PF            Phoenix Suns   $8,558,000  1999-2000
23  24        Nick Van Exel, PG          Denver Nuggets   $8,354,000  1999-2000
24  25        Elden Campbell, C       Charlotte Hornets   $7,975,000  1999-2000
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know how to check for a blank table with BeautifulSoup. Thanks!

Comment: There’s a few ways you could do it. But simply checking the length seemed like it made the most sense